# UIButtons in UIScrollView stop working after 3 rows

Tags: objective-c, uiscrollview

I have a UIScrollView with a list of UIViews within it. Bit like a fancy tableview. One issue I am having is the buttons work ok for the first 3 'rows' in the scrollview, but none of the buttons after this respond when i scroll down. Looks like its working ok for the buttons that show on screen when the view has loaded but anything further down when i scroll will now respond at all...

**code from within the uiview repeated within uiscrollview**

```
    -(void)addButtons
    {
        UIButton *visiteWebSite = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        [visiteWebSite addTarget:self
                          action:@selector(visitSite:)
         forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
        [visiteWebSite setTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:247 green:143 blue:30 alpha:1.0]];

        visiteWebSite.frame = CGRectMake(440.0, 10.0, 120.0, 26.0);
        if(![self IsPhone5]) {
            visiteWebSite.frame = CGRectMake(350.0, 10.0, 120.0, 26.0);
        }
        //visiteWebSite.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor]; //[UIColor colorWithRed:247 green:143 blue:30 alpha:1.0];
        [visiteWebSite setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"orangeBG"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [visiteWebSite setTitle:@"VISITE WEBSITE" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        visiteWebSite.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"arial" size:12];

        [self addSubview:visiteWebSite];

        UIButton *getDirections = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        [getDirections addTarget:self
                          action:@selector(getDirections:)
                forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];

        [getDirections setTitle:@"GET DIRECTIONS" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        getDirections.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"arial" size:12];
        getDirections.frame = CGRectMake(440.0, 46.0, 120.0, 26.0);
        if(![self IsPhone5]) {
            getDirections.frame = CGRectMake(350.0, 46.0, 120.0, 26.0);
        }
        [getDirections setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"orangeBG"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        [self addSubview:getDirections];
    }
```

**Code from Parent View containing the UIScrollView**

```
-(void)performSearch
{
    [self.loadinglabel removeFromSuperview];
    NSString* searchTerm = txtSearch.text;
    searchTerm = [searchTerm stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];

    NSData *urldata = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.collectioncosmetics.co.uk/storelocatorapi?store=%@",searchTerm]]];
    NSString *json = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:urldata encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    SBJsonParser *jsonParser = [[SBJsonParser alloc] init];
    NSArray *jsonObjects = [jsonParser objectWithString:json];
    float y = 0;
    float height = 84;
    if([jsonObjects count] < 1) {
        UIAlertView* alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"NO RESULTS" message:@"There are no stores near the postcode you searched" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [alertView show];
        [self back:nil];
        return;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < [jsonObjects count]; i++)
    {
        NSDictionary *dict = [jsonObjects objectAtIndex:i];
        CARStoreResult* result = [[CARStoreResult alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, height*i, tv.frame.size.width, height)];
        result.name = [dict objectForKey:@"name"];
        result.street = [dict objectForKey:@"street"];
        result.area = [dict objectForKey:@"area"];
        result.county = [dict objectForKey:@"County"];
        result.postcode = [dict objectForKey:@"PostCode"];
        result.distance = [dict objectForKey:@"distance"];
        result.usersPostCode = searchTerm;
        result.y = y;
        result.num = i;
        y = y + height;
        [result build];
        [tv addSubview:result];
    }
    [tv setFrame:CGRectMake(tv.frame.origin.x, tv.frame.origin.y, tv.frame.size.width, height*[jsonObjects count])];
    [self.scrollView setContentSize:tv.frame.size];

    [Flurry logEvent:@"Store Locator"];
}
```

Comment: How do you create the button? please post code

Comment: And what would you like us to do about it? Please ask a question and provide some code so we can see what's going on. Help us help you.

Comment: not enough code.Add the scroll and uiview code

Comment: CARStoreResult is the UIView that has the buttons

Answer (score 0):

**FIXED!**
instead of adding the views to a view within the scrollview i added them just directly to the scrollview. with the scrollview having scrollView.canCancelContentTouches set to NO.

```
    //[tv addSubview:result];
    [self.scrollView addSubview:result];
}
//[tv setFrame:CGRectMake(tv.frame.origin.x, tv.frame.origin.y, tv.frame.size.width, height*[jsonObjects count])];
[self.scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, height*[jsonObjects count])];
//[self.scrollView setContentSize:tv.frame.size];

[Flurry logEvent:@"Store Locator"];
```